# how to make input variable with only the alphabet

Tags: python, variables, input, alphabet

This is the problem I am facing. Can anyone help

```
name=input("What is your name?")
name= input.lower()
```

when it runs this is what comes up

```
What is your name?Bob

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\eval task 1 GCSE.py", line 6, in <module>
    name= input.lower()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

can anyone fix this please. I need to make sure that I can only enter letters from the alphabet for my name input. Can anyone show me how to do this. Very appreciated

Comment: You get the user input with the `input` function, then store it in a variable `name`. You then try to call the `lower` method of the `input` function which doesn't exist. Change `input.lower()` to `name.lower()`.

Comment: Your intention isn't completely clear. Do you need to reject the input outright if it contains numeric characters? Or do you want to keep the input but merely filter the non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: Basically I want make a variable called name which only accepts letter from the alphabet. If they input an integer instead then I want it to stop and print this I not a valid name

Comment: Just posted an answer for you, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

call lower on name instead:

```
name = name.lower()
```

Comment: Ryan can you help me out here. Now that it this works I was wondering how I could make validation so that if they enter an integer I can say that is invalid. Any thoughts

Comment: Doing homework? ;-) Read this:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: for example, if you don't want them entering numbers at all in their name, name.isalpha should be true, if its false--then there's a number there (or other non-alphabetic character)

Comment: I don't understand the str isalpha

Comment: What is your name?ldsnkdsb

Comment: True Your score out of 10 was 1 !

Comment: that's what happens for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
username=input("What is your name?").lower()
for char in username:
    if not char.isalpha():
        print "invalid username"
        break
```